# How to obtain values of parameters of get request in flask?

Tags: python, web, flask, get-request

The answer that I found on the web is to use `request.args.get`. However, I cannot manage it to work. I have the following simple example:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    print request.args['x']
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I go to the `127.0.0.1:5000/hello?x=2` in my browser and as a result I get:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's about half way down the [quickstart page under Accessing Request Data](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#accessing-request-data) under [context locals](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#context-locals)

Comment: what if I don't know what keys the user is sending in the request? and the headers?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The simple answer is you have not imported the `request` global object from the flask package.

```
from flask import Flask, request
```

This is easy to determine yourself by running the development server in debug mode by doing

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

This will give you a stacktrace including:

```
print request.args['x']
NameError: global name 'request' is not defined
```

Answer (score 14):

http://localhost:5000/api/iterators/opel/next**?n=5**

For something like the case before

```
from flask import Flask, request
n = request.args.get("n")
```

Can do the trick