# How to create dynamic url with = and questionmarks in flask

Tags: python, url, flask

How do I create a url in Flask that looks like:

```
localhost/something/info?userID=123&itemID=456
```

I am intressed in how to generate the info?userID=123&itemID=456 part.

Is it:

```
@app.route('something/info<userID>&<itemID>/')
do_something(userID, itemID):
    return
```

And I have seen something about "next" being used. But can't find any good example.

**Edit**

I looked at the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383458/how-to-obtain-values-of-parameters-of-get-request-in-flask) but I didn't understand the example there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain values of parameters of get request in flask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383458/how-to-obtain-values-of-parameters-of-get-request-in-flask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `userID` and `itemID` are `GET` parameters but not part of route.

Flask request has `view_args`(which will used as arguments to view) and `args`(other parameters that will not be set to view function, but you can use them).

Here an example which can explain how it works.

```
@app.route('/<string:route_arg>/')
def route(route_arg):
    message = [
        # route_arg - part of route and argument of our view function
        'route_arg = %s ' % route_arg,
        # we can get route_arg from request
        'route_arg from request = %s ' % request.view_args.get('route_arg'),
        # request.args - parameters after '?' in url
        'userID = %s' % request.args.get('userID'),
        'itemID = %s' % request.args.get('itemID'),
        # example of url
        'url with args = %s' % url_for('route', route_arg='info', userID=123, itemID=456)
    ]
    return '<br/>'.join(message)
```

Let's open `/info/` you will see the next result:

```
route_arg = info # because is part of route and argument
route_arg from request = info 
# because we didn't set parameters
userID = None 
itemID = None
url with args = /info/?itemID=456&userID=123
```

Let's open `/info/?itemID=456&userID=123`:

```
route_arg = info 
route_arg from request = info 
# not part of route, but part of request string(?itemID=456&userID=123)
userID = 123
itemID = 456
url with args = /info/?itemID=456&userID=123
```

So, in your case parameters will not used as arguments to view. You should work with them using `request.args`.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. I managed to figure it out with your example!

Comment: @FluffPeg I was glad to help. Good luck ;)